# I want to create a new column 'Assign' and assign value : Prefix 'Check' column value and Suffix as '-SPLIT' to ITEM_TYPE. EX.'TRUE-AB-SPLIT'

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Below is my original DataFrame:-

```
PRODUCT ID|  ITEM_TYPE|  CHECK
12345678  |    AB     |  TRUE
87654321  |    CD     |  FALSE
```

Excepted DataFrame:-

```
PRODUCT ID|  ITEM_TYPE|  CHECK| ASSIGN
12345678  |    AB     |  TRUE | TRUE-AB-SPLIT
87654321  |    CD     |  FALSE| FALSE-CD-SPLIT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join columns by `+` and last add string `SPLIT`:

```
df['CHECK'] = df['ITEM_TYPE'] + '-' + df['ID'] + '-SPLIT'
#if ITEM_TYPE is boolean
#df['CHECK'] = df['ITEM_TYPE'].astype(str) + '-' + df['ID'] + '-SPLIT'
print (df)
    PRODUCT  ID ITEM_TYPE           CHECK
0  12345678  AB      TRUE   TRUE-AB-SPLIT
1  87654321  CD     FALSE  FALSE-CD-SPLIT
```